# Is it feasible to force Spark data set stored on driver node (not as pandas df)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In my script, there are frequent joins of certain **small** data sets. I notice join normally takes longer than other operations, to my understanding probably because join is done only at driver node, so data from partitions need to be collected every time to the driver before joining.

Is it possible at all to make some Spark data set **stay** on the driver node, so that for next join it's already there ? I guess that may be interesting instead of collecting the same data set to driver node each time, join, then dispatch back to partitions, then next operation collect back at driver to join.

You may say using `.collect()` and work with it purely as pandas data frame on the driver node. 
I did mix and match pandas data frame and Spark data frame on several occasions. However, in my scenario, besides using on small joins it will also be used in a large join with a big data set, that I `broadcast join` at the moment.

Imagine the operation is

```
small_df = small_df.join1(...)
small_df = f1(...)
small_df = f2(...)
.....
small_df = small_df.join2(..)
...
small_df = small_df.join3(..)
result = broadcast(small_df).join(big_df)
```

Again, in both cases, I understand that the `small_df` will always be pulled back to the driver node for join. Hence ideally it would be staying in the driver node while remaining a `Spark df` and not `pandas df`.

It's just a hypothetical thought; I am not sure it's feasible or efficient at all. Perhaps it goes against the philosophy of Spark, but if it's possible I would like to try and compare it with my current approach.

Comment: Joins are not performed in the driver node, nothing is performed in the driver node. The driver node only works as a scheduler of tasks. All the work is performed on the executor nodes. Join takes longer because it is a complex operation. If you know your dataset is small, then broadcast is the best alternative. Also, if you know many things are small, then you should not be using **spark** at all for those, but only **pandas**.

Comment: ^ +1. It is also worth noting that none of the transformations from your code sample  will actually be executed until you call an action (because of Spark lazy evaluation). Once invoked somewhere down the line, an action will trigger processing of **all** the joins, not just a single one if you follow each `join()` by a  `collect()` (`collect` is an action).

Comment: rewrite result = broadcast(small_df).join(big_df) to result = big_df.join(broadcast(small_df)) if you want to optimize performance.

Comment: @Prateek interesting; can you share what the difference is ? I did notice good performance with my approach but haven't heard about writing it as second or as first.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for the input. by the way, collect(), toPandas() and other actions (show, take, first, count, sum, etc.) do perform on the driver node and bring data there, don't they ?

Comment: @Kenny they would perform all the work on the **Exceutors**, and finally send the final results to the **Driver**, the only work the driver will do, is to collect data.

Answer (score 0):

A join is performed at the executors not the driver. As long as you use the small dataset on the right hand side of the join, Spark should automatically perform a broadcast join where appropriate.

Comment: I did notice Spark would not automatically use Broadcast even with small data set on the right hand side of the join. It would just use HashJoin.

Comment: Is `spark.sql.conf.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` enabled in your config?

Comment: Nope it is not.

Comment: Well that should explain that one then!